# REGEX to get Vimeo & Dailymotion ID

Tags: ios, swift, nsregularexpression

I found two useful javascript regex but none of them seems to be working right on Swift.

This works with a Youtube URL, but doesn't with Vimeo and DailyMotion. Both Vimeo & Dailymotion regex works on javascript.

Thanks guys.

** EDIT WITH THE SOLUTION **

Thanks GreatBigBore and Larme

```
private func getVendorId(_ regexStr:String, _ videoUrl:String, _ search:[Int]) -> String {

    let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexStr, options: .caseInsensitive)
    let result:[NSTextCheckingResult] = (regex?.matches(in: videoUrl, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (videoUrl.characters.count ))))!

    if result.count > 0 {
        let groups = result.first!;
        for i in search {
            if (groups.rangeAt(i).length != 0) {
                return (videoUrl as NSString).substring(with: groups.rangeAt(i))
            }
        }
    }

    return "";
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let youtubeUrl   = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCc0V5bgEF8";
    let youtubeRegex = "((?<=(v|V)/)|(?<=be/)|(?<=(\\?|\\&)v=)|(?<=embed/))([\\w-]++)";
    let youtubeId    = getVendorId(youtubeRegex, youtubeUrl, [0]);
    print("YOUTUBE ID -> \(youtubeId)")

    let vimeoUrl    = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/233459603";
    let vimeoRegex  = "https?:\\/\\/(?:www\\.|player\\.)?vimeo.com\\/(?:channels\\/(?:\\w+\\/)?|groups\\/([^\\/]*)\\/videos\\/|album\\/(\\d+)\\/video\\/|video\\/|)(\\d+)(?:$|\\/|\\?)";
    let vimeoId     = getVendorId(vimeoRegex, vimeoUrl, [2]);
    print("VIMEO ID -> \(vimeoId)")

    let dailyMotionUrl   = "http://www.dailymotion.com/hub/x9q_Galatasaray";
    let dailyMotionRegex = "^.+dailymotion.com\\/(video|hub)\\/([^_]+)[^#]*(#video=([^_&]+))?";
    let dailyMotionId    = getVendorId(dailyMotionRegex, dailyMotionUrl, [4, 2]);
    print("DAILYMOTION ID -> \(dailyMotionId)")


    super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

Comment: `let regRes:[Any]` if you write `let regRes:[NSTextCheckingResult]` instead, you could avoid the `as? NSTextCheckingResult` in `regRes.first as? NSTextCheckingResult`. For the rest, did you checked all the `regRes` values instead of only first? What do they print? Since you have various regex group, it may be interesting to find which one is usefull for each regex.

Answer (score 0):

Your regexes are working fine. The problem is that you're not accounting for multiple capture groups. Your variable `result` will contain an `NSRange` for every capture group; you need to get your captured ID from one of those, not from `result?.range`. Here's some example code to show you what I mean. Add it to your `getId()` function, after `let result`:

```
print("Capture group count", result!.numberOfRanges)

for i in 0 ..< result!.numberOfRanges {
    if result!.range(at: i).length == 0 {
        print("Group \(i) is empty")
    } else {
        print("Group \(i) captured", (url as NSString).substring(with: result!.range(at: i)))
    }
}
```

It's not clear to me why your youtube id captured the way it did; I think it had something to do with all that look-behind (I'm not an expert with look-behind). But the problem is not with your regex; it's just that you need to get your id from the capture group, not directly from `regRes.first`.